# Adding LatLon to Polygon android google map version 2 from list

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a list full of LatLng points to create a polygon in google maps android v2, but I cannot figure out how to add this list to the .add area correctly. Here is my list full of points:

```
list.add(new LatLng(la,lo));
```

Here is the polygon via Google Dev

```
Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
.add(*******HOW TO ITTERATE LIST************).strokeColor(Color.RED)
.fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

How do you go about adding the points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PolygonOptions opts=new PolygonOptions();

for (LatLng location : list) {
  opts.add(location);
}

Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(opts.strokeColor(Color.RED).fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

This assumes that `list` is something like an `ArrayList<LatLng>`.

Comment: Thanks! That was easier than I had thought.

Comment: do you have any experience using GeoJSON and Google Map API V2 Android?

Comment: @jasonflaherty: No, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I find this without need for iteration.

```
PolygonOptions polOpt =
    new PolygonOptions().addAll(latlngs).strokeColor(Color.RED).fillColor(Color.BLUE);

Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(polOpt);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help someone. I did the same its working.

```
ArrayList<LatLng> locations = new ArrayList();
```

Adding the latLng value in list.

```
locations .add(new LatLng(2, 2));
locations .add(new LatLng(4, 2));
locations .add(new LatLng(4, 4));
locations .add(new LatLng(2, 4));
locations .add(new LatLng(2, 2))
```

Creating the GeoFence on the map

```
PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.RED).geodesic(true);
                for (int z = 0; z < locations.size(); z++) {
                    LatLng point = locations.get(z);
                    options.add(point);
                }
                mMap.addPolyline(options);
                CameraPosition cameraPosition;
                cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(50.8404969, -0.1504184)).zoom(15).build();
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```