# how to draw poly line on google map in android

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_chat);

}
@Override
onResume() {
    if (map != null) {
        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        try {
            LatLng point = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(Latreccvier),
                    Double.parseDouble(Lonreccvier));

            BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.reccivermarker);

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(point);
            markerOptions.icon(icon);
            map.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, 14));
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14), 2000, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void RealTimeLocation(int memberId, final double lat, final double lng) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Latreccvier = String.valueOf(lat);
            Lonreccvier = String.valueOf(lng);

            LatLng point1=new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(Latreccvier), Double.parseDouble(Lonreccvier));
            friendMarker.setPosition(point1);
        }
    });
}
```

this is my code i want to draw ply line on google map  i am able to move marker at same time i want to draw path of line of moving google map.

```
public void RealTimeLocation(int memberId, final double lat, final double lng) { 
a
```

using this method i am getting 4 to 5 lat long on Location changed i am trying to add `freindlatlong.add(point1);` 
where freindlatlong is array list according to that i try to add Plyline but not work please suggest me how to draw path line on map.

Comment: where you used `freindlatlong`?

Comment: myMap.addPolyline(options); using this code

Comment: But where? i cant see in your code....

Comment: please tell me how to draw i tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425499/how-to-draw-interactive-polyline-on-route-google-maps-v2-android

Comment: Without proper code i cant help you any more.

Comment: ok wait am seindg code

Comment: @MD http://paste.ofcode.org/tDGBBmT8MXxt78ht3gqcie check this code i have applied

Comment: Here is the way go to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627507/add-polygon-on-google-ampv2-android/23627754#23627754](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627507/add-polygon-on-google-ampv2-android/23627754#23627754)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
onResume() {

        if (map != null) {

            // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map

            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

            try {

                LatLng point = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(Latreccvier),
                        Double.parseDouble(Lonreccvier));

                BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.reccivermarker);

                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(point);
                markerOptions.icon(icon);
                map.addMarker(markerOptions);
                // map.addPolyline(options);
                // // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, 14));
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14), 2000, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }

    }




@Override
        public void RealTimeLocation(int memberId, final double lat,
                final double lng) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Latreccvier = String.valueOf(lat);
                    Lonreccvier = String.valueOf(lng);

                    LatLng point1 = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(Latreccvier),
                            Double.parseDouble(Lonreccvier));

                    cordinatelist.add(point1);

                    friendMarker.setPosition(point1);
                    // options.add(point1);


}
            });
        }

    };
```

please replace this code

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,very good code for drawing poly-line:

```
 MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting latitude and longitude of the marker position
            markerOptions.position(point);

            // Setting titile of the infowindow of the marker
            markerOptions.title("Position");

            // Setting the content of the infowindow of the marker
            markerOptions.snippet("Latitude:"+point.latitude+","+"Longitude:"+point.longitude);

            // Instantiating the class PolylineOptions to plot polyline in the map
            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Setting the color of the polyline
            polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);

            // Setting the width of the polyline
            polylineOptions.width(3);

            // Adding the taped point to the ArrayList
            points.add(point);

            // Setting points of polyline
            polylineOptions.addAll(points);

            // Adding the polyline to the map
            googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

            // Adding the marker to the map
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

**Reference :**   [Adding poly-line on tap](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-polyline-and-markers-along-the-tapped-positions-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-arraylist/)